# Cannot find Pentaho Reporting config file

Tags: debian, pentaho, business-intelligence, pentaho-report-designer

We have a Pentaho suite  version 5.2 installation on a Debian 8 machine. I was not the responsible one for setting up the Pentaho Server and my knowledge is limited to the documentation. We’re doing some testing and I found somewhere on the internet that I need to modify a config file parameter to test something out. The parameter is:

`org.pentaho.reporting.engine.classic.core.modules.misc.tablemodel.TableFactoryMode=simple`

I have tried to search the entire system for this parameter with grep, no luck.

Where exactly is the file which contains this configuration?

If there is no file, do I need to manually add the parameter to the Pentaho Reporting main configuration file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The file should be `classic-engine.properties` in the root of your classpath.

On my windows pentaho CE the file is `biserver-ce/tomcat/webapps/pentaho/WEB-INF/classes/classic-engine.properties`.

Your parameter is likely to be not specified in the config file by default, so the default value will be used, until you add the parameter to the file manually and restart the server.

Comment: Yeah I had found the file but not the parameter so i didn't knew if I needed to add it manually. Will test it and report back, thank you!